# Volley pass a response outside of the class

Tags: android, android-volley

I want to pass a response outside of my classes (many classes)

```
public static void userLocation()
 {

     RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
   String url = "http://www.jobdiagnosis.com/iphone/userlocation.php";

     StringRequest dr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, 
                new Response.Listener<String>() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // response

                        //Toast.makeText(context, ""+response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }, 
                new Response.ErrorListener() 
                {
                     @Override
                     public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                         // error.
                        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error"+error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         Log.d("error", ""+error);
                   }
                }
            );
            queue.add(dr);

 }
```

Please suggest how I can pass a response outside of the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In volly its difficult to return response outside the class.because request on server run in background and if we return value followed by queue.add(url) then it will return null.So there is no solution till now.Thanks!!